# To remove the square brackets from pyspark dataframe column values

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe column with the value of:

however, what's my expected result is to remove the square brackets before & after the curly brackets:

| drivers | expected_column |
| --- | --- |
| [{"driverId":"2015016200-3edf","driverName":"Dianne Uy"}] | {"driverId":"2015016200-3edf","driverName":"Dianne Uy"} |

```
df= (df
     .withColumn("drivers", f.from_json("drivers", driver_schema))
     .withColumn("expected_column", f.col("drivers").getItem(0))
    )
```

But, I have got this error
AnalysisException: [INVALID_EXTRACT_FIELD_TYPE] Field name should be a non-null string literal, but it's "0".

Other ways to achieve my expected column/result?

Comment: yes, and this is the runtime version 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: what's the data type of `drivers` column?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can use the `get_json_object` function from PySpark, which allows you to extract the first JSON object from the "drivers" column.

Below is sample code snippet:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Remove Square Brackets") \
    .getOrCreate()
data = [
    ('[{"driverId":"2015016200-3edf","driverName":"Dianne Uy"}]',),
]
schema = "drivers STRING"
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df = df.withColumn("expected_column", get_json_object("drivers", "$[0]"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]